# How to change current server calendar date to another calendar date in php?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, datetimepicker

I'm gonna change current date to new date in php, In following code current date shows on page in Persian calendar, but it doesn't change real Gregorian date.

**For example:** If we stored date: 2015-01-03 in database, this code convert this date to new date in Persian Calendar and it will show it on page.

[image]

```
public static function localDate($date = "")
{
    $local = "";
switch (strlen($date))
    {
   default: // Ymd
      {
      if (( $date < '19700101'))
      {
    $local = $date;
    break;
      }
      else
      {
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/jdatetime.class.php';
        $local = jDateTime::date("l j F Y", strtotime($date), true, true, 'Asia/Tehran');
        break;
      }
    }
    break;
}
return $local;
```

}

Here is [jdatetime.class.php](https://github.com/sallar/jDateTime/blob/master/jdatetime.class.php)

**Question: How can I change current date to new date in server? I'm gonna store date based on Persian Calendar** How to changed server date from Gregorian to Persian calendar?

Here's sample of my problem:

[image]

Comment: Is `date_default_timezone_set` what you want?

Comment: I'm gonna change default time zone to Persian calendar how to do it ?

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set("name_of_persion_timezone");`. I don't know the name of the timezone, I assume you do.

Comment: Actually I did it but it doesn't work,   define("OPEN_TIME_ZONE",       "Asia/Tehran");

Comment: Time zone is a completely separate concept from calendar system. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: AFAIK there's no built-in support for different calendar systems, timezones are just for the time of day. I didn't understand the question before. You'll probably have to google for something like "PHP persian calendar", maybe you'll find a third-party library that does it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did this way too, if you see my above code, I'm using jdatetime.class.php , it means third party  library!!! please have a look into this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380573/how-to-store-date-in-database-based-on-different-calendars